# Mixed Teams: What is the definition of Ready and Done in a mixed team with test participation?

Tags: test-management, team-management, scrum, testing-team

**Details:**

We are in a project in which many different teams are working (Safe Scrum), which are located in different locations, and are currently still working on other tasks, but which will inevitably be merged.

We are now planning Mixed Teams from all teams for the tasks of merging the tasks.

But what is the definition of Ready and Done in a mixed team with test participation?

Comment: What do you mean with mixed team? Cross-functional?

Comment: Note that every team has testing, even if it doesn't have a "tester" - any team investigate their work somehow looking for threats to the product success. I’m voting to close this question because it's in the scope of Product management. https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am against it because of course also the test within the definition of ready and done must be attributed a special role, here also in particular to the alignment of the cross/mixed team strategy. Not every strategy can be generalized purely to product management, but in particular I have pointed out above that I only mean the test explicitly here.

Comment: I asked a similar question months ago in product management, there they closed it because the question would be too test-heavy ^^

Answer (score 2):

The Defintion of Ready and Done is very context, risks and team depended. Depending on the quality needs of the product you might need more or less in these definitions. There is not a one size fits all.

That is why I would suggest you sit down with your team and write down what information you need to start on work (ready) and what [DoneDone](https://www.jamesshore.com/v2/books/aoad1/done_done) means for your team. Normaly a Scrum Master would facilitate this.

I would start with the following items in my DoR and DoD and during the retrospective extend it if needed.

Definition of Ready:

- We have enough information for a ballpark estimate and the work-unit (PBI) is around 1/5th of an itteration (Sprint)
- We think we can built, test and deploy it

Definition of Done:

- We deployed it to production
- We validated that the users are using the new feature and if not ask why not and learn

Answer (score 1):

https://www.scaledagileframework.com/agile-teams/

> **Explore, Integrate, Deploy, and Release Independently Planning,**
>
> demoing, and learning together creates the alignment that enables
> teams to independently and reliably deliver value. Agile teams drive
> value through the entire continuous delivery pipeline. Collaborating
> with product management around continuous exploration, they
> continuously integrate, and they continuously deploy their work to
> staging and (ideally) production environments. While Agile teams
> strive to independently deploy and release their parts of solutions,
> some technical, regulatory, and other hurdles may hinder them. In
> those situations, teams coordinate and align their deployment and
> release to production. Agile teams help validate feature hypotheses by
> deploying to production early and frequently. They design their
> systems in ways that permit decoupling the solution from the release,
> enabling the ability to release on demand.

Just add to above answer , even in SAFe Agile each team should ideally work independently so the definition of done and ready should be specific to each team and context

https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/4-biggest-challenges-moving-scaled-agile-framework-safe

Explains more about the concept ,